# xor unsupported operand error in case of using yield instead of return in key generation function

Tags: python, encryption, xor

I have a script that take a file and considering its size, (in the following code less than 416 bytes) using series of hash operations, a mask is generated (using keygen function below) to be XORed with the input file (below in cipher function). I want the keys to be generated on demand for better memory efficiency. but in the keygen function when I use yield instead of return my cipher function returns the error:

```
CD = bytearray((x ^ y for (x, y) in zip(file, key)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'bytearray'
```

here is the code:

```
from hashlib import md5
def keygen(f, pk): #takes file f as input (here data size is less than 4126bytes)
    ck=bytearray(b'')
    l=len(f)
    if l <= 28*16:
        for i in pk:
            a=md5(i.encode())
            ck += a.digest()
    yield ck
```

the following function does the encryption:

```
def cipher(file, key):
    out=bytearray(b'')
    out = bytearray((x ^ y for (x, y) in zip(file, key)))
    return out
```

at the end of my script I have:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    file = bytearray(open('C:\\code\\Test.txt', 'rb').read()) 
    pk = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    key = keygen(file, pk)
    output = cipher(file, key)
    final=open('out.data', 'wb')
    final.write(output)
    final.close()
```

the whole process works just fine if I use return in keygen function instead of yield, but fails otherwise. 
I want the keys be generated on demand considering the data size inside the cipher function. but the keygen function seem not to be compatible if I use yield instead of return.

I read the file bytearray format and defined the ck in keygen as bytearray too. in I tried yield bytearray(ck) in keygen but that does not work either.

what point am I missing? How can I generate the keys on-demand considering the data size?

Comment: I don't think yield does what you think it does.

Comment: as far as I have read, yield returns a generator thus can be used to get the results on demand. My goal is that in cipher function file be xored with the key stream being generated byte per byte. Is there any way you think?

Comment: Using `yield` makes a function a generator, but the object returned by yield is (usually) _not_ a generator.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: It is Okay I as far as I see, where exactly you mean?

Comment: @Kebin: Any solution for the goal I seek?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short:

```
def keygen(f, pk): #takes file f as input (here data size is less than 4126bytes)
    l=len(f)
    if l <= 28*16:
        for i in pk:
            a=md5(i.encode())
            yield a.digest()
```

Comment: @Miind: Please see the Python docs so you understand how to use generators. Eg https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 0):

```
from hashlib import md5
def keygen(f, pk):
    if len(f) > len(pk)*16:
        pk = ''
    return (ord(ch) for letter in pk for ch in md5(letter).digest())
```